# Change visible in Contents C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm trying to make a support page for a system,in this page i have a radio button list,in this page i have four contents,i want to set the four to visible=false,when i choose one of the buttons,the content change to visible = true.But in the .cs file i can't see the content neither the placeholder,i dont know why,and the content don't show in the designer file,but the contentplaceholder shows in the master page designer file.I also don't know if i should call the contentName or the contentPlaceHolderName.

Here's the code

Base.master

```
 <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div id="stage">
                                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ctrlPageHeader" runat="server" />
                                <div class="pageTitle">
                                    <asp:Label CssClass="pageTitle" ID="lblPageTitle" runat="server"></asp:Label></div>
                                <br />
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="contentDetail">
                                <p>
                                    <asp:Label CssClass="ErrorMessage" ID="lblMasterPageDisplayError" runat="server"></asp:Label></p>
                                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ctrlMainContentArea" runat="server" />
                               <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ctrlSuportArea" runat="server"/>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ctrlFlowBug" runat="server"/>
                                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ctrlManager" runat="server"/>
                                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ctrlCTG" runat="server"/>
```

The supportPage.cs

```
 public void RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ContentPlaceHolder area = (ContentPlaceHolder)Page.Master.FindControl(beneficiaryArea);
          beneficiaryArea.Visible = false;          

        FindControl("beneficiaryArea").Visible = false; 

        FindControl("managerEmployee").Visible = false;

        FindControl("ctgAnalyst").Visible = false;

        FindControl("flowCorrection").Visible = false;


        if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex.Equals(1))
        {
            FindControl(beneficiaryArea).Visible = true;
        }

        else if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex.Equals(2))
        {
            FindControl(managerEmployee).Visible = true;


        }
        else if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex.Equals(3))
        {

            FindControl(ctrlCTG).Visible = true;

        }
        else if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex.Equals(4))
        {

            FindControl(flowCorrection).Visible = true;
        }

    }
```

The SupportPage.aspx

```
<asp:Content ID="beneficiaryArea" ContentPlaceHolderID="ctrlSuportArea" runat="server">
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <td align="left" style="width: 20%">
        <b>Atual Área Beneficiada</b>
    </td>
    <td align="left" style="width: 27%">
        <asp:Label ID="lblBeneficiaryArea" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <td align="left" style="width: 20%">
            <b>Nova Área Beneficiada</b>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ListBeneficiaryArea" runat="server">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
    </td>
</table>
<br />
<br />
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to find controls that don't even exist on the page. Where is this: beneficiaryArea ? Or managerEmployee? I feel like you missed pasting the front-end code for supportPagem and you only pasted the code-behind.

Comment: Set all ContentPlaceHolders in the markup to visible = false;
And make only one visible in your code behind

Comment: Added the SupportPage.aspx

Comment: I can set the visible to false,the problem is when i select in the button,i can't change to visible because i can't see the content in the cs file,the error says:"Cannot Resolve Symbol 'managerEmployee' ",i deleted the designer file and create again,but in the designer i still don't see the content managerEmployee,should i see or its normal?

Comment: I resolved,i used panels instead of changing the visible of contents.